# Unable to find correct records between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am trying to find records between to dates using `>=` and `<=` operator but result are not getting proper.

I have two input box for passing user selected dates:

```
company_date_from (15/04/2015)
company_date_to (20/04/2015)
```

and table which is `tma_38` and my date field name is `created_date (timestamp)`

Table Records:

```
company_id  created_date
----------  -------------------
10          2015-04-15 10:49:26
13          2015-04-17 09:49:06
14          2015-04-21 14:59:42
15          2015-05-20 14:26:07
16          2015-04-21 18:42:00
```

The query I am using:

```
SELECT *
FROM tma_38
WHERE city LIKE '%%'
AND DATE_FORMAT( created_date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) >= '15/04/2015'
AND DATE_FORMAT( created_date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) <= '21/04/2015'
ORDER BY created_date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Currently, it is returning all results which is what I don't want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you still working to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Use the sql between like so

```
created_date between $filter["company_date_from"] and $filter["company_date_to"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it the wrong way around. Don't convert the date into a string. Convert the string intput into a date.

Change

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) >= '15/04/2015'
```

to

```
AND created_date >= STR_TO_DATE('15/04/2015','%d/%m/%Y')
```

or use the default date format

```
SELECT *
FROM tma_38
WHERE city LIKE '%%'
AND created_date >= '2015-04-15'
AND created_date < '2015-04-22'
ORDER BY created_date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

I chose the `2015-04.22` instead of `21` because you store the time part also.

Comment: Can you please check my question becouse have updated my question.

Comment: Should be `DATE_FORMAT( created_date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) < '21/04/2015'`. No need of `=` if you want  data before `21`.

Comment: Hi. I have used this sql `SELECT * FROM tma_38 WHERE city LIKE '%%' AND created_date >= '2015-04-15' AND created_date <= '2015-04-21' ORDER BY created_date ASC LIMIT 0 , 10` and getting only two records. I am getting this records `1>> 2015-04-15 10:49:26 2>> 2015-04-17 09:49:06`

Comment: It should work. Check it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f49a6/2 Notice, that you won't get records from the `21th` if you don't use the `22th` because having a time makes the date bigger than only the `21th` without a time.

Answer (score 0):

Change and set the date format of the filter. Try with -

```
AND created_date <= '".date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtorime(str_replace('/', '-', $filter['company_date_to'])))."'"
```

Or you can try with `BETWEEN` -

```
created_date BETWEEN 
'".date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtorime(str_replace('/', '-', $filter['company_date_from '])))."' 
AND 
'".date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtorime(str_replace('/', '-', $filter['company_date_to'])))."'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this won't work is because dates formatted in strings like that can't work properly.

The string comparison starts at the beginning, so a number like `10/04/2010` is going to be considered greater than `04/04/2015` which is clearly not true. Part of the reason dates are stored using the [ISO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is because the `yyyy-mm-dd` format prevents incorrect string comparisons like that.

Also, your table design can be used to your advantage because the column is stored as a `timestamp`, and MySQL already has several [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) designed to work with these types.

To fix your query, you need to treat the values as the `timestamp` type that they are, and like other types in MySQL, you can use comparison operators on them. So, to check for dates between a range, you can do one of the two following:

```
WHERE myDate >= startDate AND myDate <= endDate
---
WHERE myDate BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

both of those options are equivalent, some people believe `BETWEEN` is more readable, but it is personal preference for you. Note that in these examples startDate and endDate should also be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.